# In /var/log/messages, what is: Watching system buttons [...] Power Button

Tags: linux, logging, redhat, systemd

Currently reading through **/var/log/messages** and I can see occurrences of:

```
*systemd-logind: Watching power buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)*

*systemd-logind: Watching power buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)*
```

What do these entries mean on a RHEL system?

Answer (score 2):

Those simply mean that the [systemd-logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html) service detected the hardware power and sleep buttons and is watching to see if either are pressed. If they are pressed, then systemd-logind will handle what to do.

From the docs:

```
systemd-logind is a system service that manages user logins. It is responsible for:
    ...snip...
    * Handling of power/sleep hardware keys
    ...snip...
```